# Find a json in Mongodb containing a subjson

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a `json` in `mongodb`:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("540492a9bf28b029d8f4e4b5"), 
    "type" : "liked", 
    "userid" : "2", 
    "coffeeid" : "5", 
    "attributes" : {
                       "Milk" : [  "true" ], 
                       "Sugar" : [  "unknown" ] 
                   } 
}
```

I would like to find it with a query similar to this one:

```
db.event.find({"attributes" : {"Milk" : ["true"]}})
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
db.event.find({"attributes.Milk": "true"})
```